# Is there a way to perform an OnSaving() validation with ORMLite?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I am working towards replacing an existing "heavy" commercial ORM with ServiceStack's ORMLite. In the heavy ORM, we have the ability to hook an "OnSaving" or "BeforeSaving" method to perform a validation prior to saving to the database. These methods are wired into the MyObject.Save() and occur automatically so that no upstream projects forget to call a validation method.

We currently rely on this mechanism to perform validations, address a few performance denormalizations, and assure data integrity. It's a great way to consolidate the validation into the model. (We can hopefully avoid the arguments about using a repository pattern here.)

I have searched and reviewed several ORMLite examples without finding a way to do this. Can anyone provide some clues?

Comment: Also just checked through the ORMLite source to see if there were any obvious hooks in the extensions. None found...what's the best practice for performing pre-save validation here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know none micro orms don't support events, so you have to do it manually. I don't know your code but I will try to describe what you can do:
1. Add interface IValidation with method Validate() which return collection of i.e validation results
2. Add implementation of IValidation to each object which has OnSaving method.
3. Create generic repository pattern for you micro orm with method Save
4. In method save check if the saving object implement IValidation interface if yes, then invoke Validate() method and if collection is not empty then notify user in any way you want.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I had to draw a similar conclusion. I guess that's the price you pay for the "micro" part.